# Get total amount for each individual row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on at the moment whereby I need to multiply 2 input values (quantity & amount) and then get the total. My issue lies with getting the total for each individual 'row' ideally on keyup as there will be multiple rows / fieldsets.

HTML:

```
<fieldset>

<p>Title</p>
<label id="">Quantity</label><input type="text" class="quantity" id="" value="Quantity" name="">
<label id="">Amount</label><input type="text" class="amount" id="" value="Amount" name="">
<label id="">Total</label><input type="text" class="total" id="" value="Total" name="">

</fieldset>

<fieldset>

<p>Title</p>
<label id="">Quantity</label><input type="text" class="quantity" id="" value="Quantity" name="">
<label id="">Amount</label><input type="text" class="amount" id="" value="Amount" name="">
<label id="">Total</label><input type="text" class="total" id="" value="Total" name="">

</fieldset>
```

Multiple rows can be added via a button. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

On the [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) of each input, you can get the value of each textbox using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and then multiply.

```
$("fieldset input").keyup(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).parent().find(".quantity").val();
    var amount = $(this).parent().find(".amount").val();

    $(this).parent().find(".total").val(quantity * amount);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twMSG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).delegate(".total", "keyup", function() {
  var $fieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset"),
      total = $fieldset.find(".quantity").val() * $fieldset.find(".amount").val();
  $(this).val(total);
});
```

Comment: However, please note, that: *As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. [source](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)*

Comment: Many thanks for all the help guys, sachleens example worked a treat :)